# Relative gradient error

Tags: tensorflow

Is there an easy way to calculate relative gradient error in tensorflow? All what is available is tf.test.compute_gradient_error but it computes absolute gradient error and not relative error. Of courser there're methods which compute numeric and theoretical jacobians but they are private.

Comment: Relative error is recommended to check in a model in  http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#gradcheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself tf.test.compute_gradient returns two jacobians, so I can use them to find the relative gradient error. I.e. if I use L-infinity norm, I can take tf.test.compute_gradient_error and divide in on the maximum element of both jacobians.